# SQLITE3 python Delete rows based on the string date yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss

Tags: python, sqlite, datetime, sql-delete, python-datetime

I have a big SQLITE3 database like this:

[image]

Where the field "date_" is a string formatted like so YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS

I want to delete all rows before 2020. I did something like that, but it seems I need to convert all date in an integer for sqlite3. I am a bit lost how to do it so. Here is my idea :

```js
def delete_rows_before_2020(con):
    cursorObj = con.cursor() #create connection to the BDD
    cursorObj.execute('DELETE FROM my_bdd WHERE date_ <= CAST(strftime('%s', '2020-01-01')  AS  integer')
    con.commit()
```

This doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the timestamp doesn't match what's in your photo...

Anyways, you should be storing your date strings in the  normal `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` format. Then you can just use `WHERE date_ <= '2020-01-01'`.

Or store them as integers using Unix time to save space and have faster comparisons.